# 'No write concern mode named 'majority`' found in replica set configuration' error

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to insert an object into mongodb via a POST request. The object that I send gets inserted in the db successfully, however I get the error mentioned above.

The package I'm using for mongo db:

> https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver

Connection string

> mongodb+srv://user:password@bookcluster.pxcqs.mongodb.net/DBname?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

The way I set up the database connection:

```golang
var DbConn *mongo.Client //*sql.DB //*mongo.Client

func SetupDB(conn_str string) {
    var err error
    DbConn, err = mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(conn_str))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = DbConn.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

My object:

```golang
package book

import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"

type Book struct {
    Id        primitive.ObjectID `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title     string             `json:"title" bson:"title"`
    Author    string             `json:"author" bson:"author"`
    Year      int                `json:"year" bson:"year"`
    ShortDesc string             `json:"shortDesc" bson:"shortDesc"`
    Genre     string             `json:"genre" bson:"genre"`
}
```

Here's how I send the request inside insertBook() (where b is of type Book):

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    result, err := database.DbConn.Database(dbName).Collection(collectionName).InsertOne(ctx, b)
```

Full error text:

> multiple write errors: [{write errors: []},
> {(UnknownReplWriteConcern) No write concern mode named 'majority`'
> found in replica set configuration}]

[My request in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULpHe.png)

I'm not sure if I'm missing some sort of a configuration setting somewhere - I just started with mongoDB
I tried to follow the example set in these tutorials: [3](https://medium.com/better-programming/building-a-restful-api-with-go-and-mongodb-93e59cbbee88), [4](https://medium.com/@faygun89/create-rest-api-with-golang-and-mongodb-d38d2e1d9714) and they don't seem to mention anything about the 'write concern' and 'majority'.
Also tried looking into the documentation and googling the error but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Are you sure your MongoDB is at least v2.4 or higher?

Comment: @kostix I am using it through Atlas, so that should be fine I suppose(?)

Comment: Also: it's totally not clear how your database object is created (and which Go package are you using to access MongoDB). (And I honestly have no idea what "Atlas" is; does it relate to programming in Go? You mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-atlas)?)

Comment: @kostix edited my question, thanks. Yep, that's what I meant.

Comment: @kostix Ok, got that in as well.

Comment: Can we also see the connection string used (with any passwords, if any, replaced with something like "***")? ;-)

Comment: @kostix got it )

Comment: @kostix omg, just found it! The error disappeared when I removed the options that came after the '?' in the connection string..... 
Thanks so much

Comment: Yeah, that `w=majority` looks like it. Anyway, if you've just copied and pasted it form somewhere, it's always a good idea to first weed out anything you do not directly understand, anyway ;-)

Comment: @kostix Yeah, copied it from MongoDB Atlas's official example though, so assumed it was fine for general usage, gonna be more vigilant next time x)

Comment: If you followed the published documentation and are using the current driver version this sounds like a bug in the driver.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
"mongoURI" : "mongodb+srv://${ db user name }:${ db password }@cluster0.mde0j.mongodb.net/cluster0?retryWrites=true&w=majority "
```

> I get the same error with this
> when I'm trying to insert an object into mongodb via a POST request. The object that I send gets inserted in the db successfully, however I get the error errmsg: "No write concern mode named 'majority' found in replica set configuration".

its simple error you need to delete the **&w=majority** part at the end and it will be solved

Comment: Weid. It was working for me with that `&w=majority` in the end but then all the sudden it started to give me the same error message. I removed and it works again. Why it worked before?

Comment: It works as I want.

Answer (score 20):

The problem isn't with `&w=majority`. If your connection String is inside .env file, then write it like this one below without single or double quotations and without a semicolon at the end.

```
URI=mongodb+srv://user:password@bookcluster.pxcqs.mongodb.net/DBname?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this saved me!:)

Comment: This kind of mistakes can be easily overcome using an extension like Prettier with a setting such as `{ trailingComma": "all" }`

Answer (score 3):

I was encountering same error using node.js:

```
 MongoWriteConcernError: No write concern mode named 'majority/' found in replica set configuration"
```

It was caused due to data was not getting written in database before catch block.

```
 async function connectToDatabase() {
    try {
          await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_STRING, {
             useNewUrlParser: true,
             useUnifiedTopology: true,
             writeConcern: { w: 'majority' },
          });
          console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
       } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
       }
    }
```

By adding "writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }," the bug was removed

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with an extra white space at the end of the connection string. In my case, I removed the white space and all was well.

Comment: I got this error by leaving an extra quote in the URI on accident. I guess this is mostly caused by a bad config.

Answer (score 1):

```
mongodb+srv://user:password@bookcluster.pxcqs.mongodb.net/DBname?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
```

Remove this ( ` ) at end of the URI because this will cause a "*No write concern mode named 'majority' found in replica set configuration*" error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete everything after `mongodb.net/{databaseName}?retryWrites=true&w=majority` and make it clean and neat like below

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://{nameOfAdmin}:{password}@atlascluster.ux104bi.mongodb.net/{databaseName}", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
```

Answer (score 1):

remove double quotes at the end of mongodb url

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in my case i removed / in the end of the uri and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have also faced this same error. My solution for that when i removed forward slash from last(this one --> majority/), my problem solved.

Error facing string:-
mongodb+srv://deepu:IvZ98NCXTOV7ro3M@cluster0.m13scys.mongodb.net/employeeDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority/

Solved String:-
mongodb+srv://deepu:IvZ98NCXTOV7ro3M@cluster0.m13scys.mongodb.net/employeeDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error with the connection string--->

**instead use the connection string as**-"mongodb+srv://deepu:IvZ98NCXTOV7ro3M@cluster0.m13scys.mongodb.net/(databasename)"

Delete everything that is in between .net/ and the database name.

Hope this solves your query!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the use of space or semi colon at the end of url which you have define at the .env file. So don't use any quotation or double quotation or semicolon or space
MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://Hussain_Siddiqui:Hsrusher8$$@chatapp.aw5bzak.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
Still have that warning remove &w=majority from url

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing &w=majority. Then I went to take a short nap. Again I wrote &w=majority to uri. It worked very well.

What is happening ! I do not know. Jusi it worked !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33366258)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue.
Removing the ; at the end of the connection string solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the end of the URL, there's probably a `space` or a comma `;` which are unacceptable characters in `.env`.

I had the same error and the reason was a comma:

```
DB_URI = mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.8fir3uv.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority,
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using mongoose-7.0.3 on nodeJs, and had encountered the same exception.

The fix , in my case was the following, add a parameter after the w=majority, like &maxPoolSize=5

**?retryWrites=true&w=majority&maxPoolSize=5**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Just start your Database name with capital letter**
it work's for me

Answer (score -1):

Removing the semicolon after the URI from the .env file saved me.

**Error:**
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.hcyv7.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority;

**Solved:**
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.hcyv7.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority