# Consecutive calls to updateOne of mongodb: 3rd one does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I receive 3 post calls from client, let say in a second, and with `nodejs-mongodb` **immediately**(without any pause, sleep, etc) I try to insert the data that is posted in database using `updateOne`. All data is new, so in every call, insert would happen.

Here is the code (js):

```
const myCollection = mydb.collection("mydata")

myCollection.updateOne({name:req.data.name},{$set:{name:req.data.name, data:req.data.data}}, {upsert:true}, function(err, result) {console.log("UPDATEONE err: "+err)})
```

When I call just 1 time this `updateOne`, it works; 2 times successively, it works. But if I call 2+ times in succession, only the first two ones correctly inserted into database, and the rest, no.

The error that I get after `updateOne` is, `MongoWriteConcernError: No write concern mode named 'majority;' found in replica set configuration`. However, I always get this error, also even when the insertion is done correctly. So I don't think this is related to my problem.

Probably you will suggest to me to use `updateMany`, `bulkWrite`, etc. and you will be right, but I want to know the reason why after 2+ the insertion is not done.

Comment: I think you should use `await` Also be aware of [NoSQL-Injection](https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have in mind `.updateOne()` returns a Promise so it should be handled properly in order to avoid concurrency issues. [More info about it here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.updateOne/#collection.updateone--).

The error `MongoWriteConcernError` might be related to the connection string you are using. Check if there is any `&w=majority` and remove it as [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65305856/no-write-concern-mode-named-majority-found-in-replica-set-configuration-err).

Comment: you were right about MongoWriteConcernError